# Vue.js v-on:submit (@submit) not working on iPhone/iPad

Tags: ios, vue.js, submit, preventdefault

I have a few forms in a Vue.js app that I've built that all use the @submit event handler. This works just fine in Windows and on my Android device, but it breaks on iPhone/iPad (it doesn't work). The code looks like this:

```
    <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0" @submit="submit">
        <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" v-model.trim="email" type="email" name="email" placeholder="E-mail" aria-label="E-mail">
        <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" v-model.trim="password" type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" aria-label="Password">
        <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0">Login</button>
    </form>
```

The `submit` method looks like this:

```
submit () {
      event.preventDefault()
      Api().post('/login', {
          'email' : this.email,
          'password' : this.password
      }).then((res) => {
        if (res.data.success === 'yes') {
          this.$router.push('/profile')
        }
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err)
      })
    }
```

I'm not sure if it's the @submit listener that's just not working with iOS, or if it's the event.preventDefault() that's causing the problem...??

Comment: You can do the preventDefault by using the [`.prevent` modifier](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html#Event-Modifiers). It probably won't fix your problem, but nice to know.

Comment: What version of iOS? I remember a couple years ago I discovered iOS didn't support arrow functions. iOS versions 10.2+ do support them.

Comment: Nice tip Roy J, I think I'll add that and see what happens...Eric Guan, the iPad I'm testing on is running 11.2.1

Comment: I'm having an issue where if I use `@@click='onSubmit()'` to call my submit method in Vue, it works. But if I change that to `v-on:submit='onSubmit()'` it does not do anything when clicked. Doesn't call the method. Idk why.

Comment: It is a late response, but do check `submit (event) { ...` event should be passed in the method

Answer (score 1):

According to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Method_definitions#Browser_compatibility, this syntax is not supported in IOS safari.

```
{
    methods: {
        submit(){
            // this is not supported in ios safari
        }
    }
}
```

You can setup babel to compile the Javascript. Alternatively, this should work for you too.

```
{
    methods: {
        submit: function () {
            // this is supported
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm using babel already, this isn't the problem. Thanks though